# How to filter the OneSignal push message by the mobile devise preferences settings

Tags: android, ios, push-notification, onesignal

I am very new with OneSignal. From my devise, I could

- Register a devise by segment with sendTag("threshold", 2)
- Resgister the same devise to another segmebt with sendTage("field", 1);

Frorm a PHP script I can send a push notification to a segment (I show the code below).

**Context:**

a mobile user need to monitor the bud temperature of a field.
There is two windyard owner and there is one field by owner to monitor.
There is 4 mobile phones: two by fields

In onther word
mobile_11 monitor field 1
mobile_12 monitor field 1
mobile_21 monitor field 2
mobile_22 monitor field 2

My APP give the possibilities to the user mobile to choose with field he want to monitor **and** to defined the threshold temperature.

- If the buds temperature of field 1 is below the threshold, a push message need to be sent only to mobile_11 and mobile_12
- If the buds temperature of field 2 is below the threshold, a push message need to be sent only to mobile_21 and mobile_22

**OneSignal**
OneSignal is great tool.
I created three segments

- field-1 => field is 1
- field-2 => field is 2
- threshold => threshold exist

My APP has two forms, one for the field and one for the threshold

[image]

('Terrain' is field with the id 1, 'Alarme' is the threshold)

Form my Android, I checked field 1 and a threshold of 8.
In my OneSignal console, I can now observed this line (from user tab)

[image]

I am not sure if my way to do that is the best way and may be I would have to adapt about my two forms, but from that point, I wonder how I can modify my php script to send a push notification **only to**:

- user mobile register to the segment with 'filed:1'
- user mobile register to the segment 'threshold' but with a **value of 8**

I tried the following but the threshold value is not considered

```
function sendMessage() {
    $content      = array(
        "en" => 'Une station est en alarme'
    );


    $fields = array(
        'app_id' => "55555555-xxxxx-4100-bb42-xxxxxxxxx", // wrong app_id
        'included_segments' => array(
            'threshold'
        ),
        'data' => array(
            "threshold" => "2"
        ),
        'contents' => $content
    );
    
    $fields = json_encode($fields);
    print("\nJSON sent:\n");
    
    echo '<pre>';
    print($fields);
    echo '</pre>';

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8',
        'Authorization: Basic ZTkYYYYYYYMtYTBhMi00ZTY3LYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY' // Wrong Authorisation
    ));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    
    return $response;
}
```

In the above example, the push message is sent, which should not because the threshold is actualy at 8

Do you understand my issue?
If not, please feel free to ask me additional information
WHich would be the best way to do that?
It must work on IOS and Android

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have got some good result (see code below) but I need to send a message when the the temperature is below the threshold to segment 1 and 0 or to segement 2 and 0.

To resume, I have two field wine (later I can have more field to monitor)

A user can be registered to field 1. He is register to segment field-1
A other user can be registered to field 2. He is register to segment field-2
A user can be register to segment field-0 to be alarm when a temprerature is below of the threshold of any fields.

This code work fine but it will never alarm a user registered to the segment field-0

```
 'filters' => array(
                array(
                    "field"     => "tag", 
                    "key"       => "threshold", 
                    "relation"  => ">", 
                    "value"     => $lowestTemperature),
                array(
                    "operator"  => "AND"),
                array(
                    "field"     => "tag", 
                    "key"       => "field",
                    "relation"  => "=", 
                    "value"     => $fieldID
                    )
            ),
```

Note: $fieldID will never get a value of 0

Then I tried the following wihtout success

```
     'filters' => array(
        array(
            array(
                "field"     => "tag", 
                "key"       => "threshold", 
                "relation"  => ">", 
                "value"     => $lowestTemperature
            ),
            array(
            "operator"  => "AND"
            ),
            array(
                "field"     => "tag", 
                "key"       => "field",
                "relation"  => "=", 
                "value"     => $fieldID
            )

        ),
        array(
            "operator"  => "OR"
        ),
        array(
           array(
                "field"     => "tag", 
                "key"       => "threshold", 
                "relation"  => ">", 
                "value"     => $lowestTemperature
            ),
            array(
            "operator"  => "AND"
            ),
            array(
                "field"     => "tag", 
                "key"       => "field",
                "relation"  => "=", 
                "value"     => 0
            )
        )
    ),
```

Would have any solution to have something similar to

```
if(($value < $threshold AND $field == $fieldID) OR ($value < $threshold AND $field == 0))
{
  // Send push notification
}
```